# time based trigger doesn't work as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

We are testing new lunch order system for company.

Time based trigger doesn't work as expected, our goal is to start and stop accept response by time, also, send out email to everyone in the company and remind them to order lunch.

```
/**
 * Specify the form to operate on
 */
var formId = '-';
var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

/**
 * Set this up as a time-based trigger to open your form at
 * a specific date & time.
 */
function startAcceptingResponses() {
  form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
}

/**
 * Set this up as a time-based trigger to close your form at
 * a specific date & time.
 */
function stopAcceptingResponses() {
  form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
}

function sendEmails() {
  var emailAddress = "thomas@abc.com";
  var message = "Please choose your lunch from this link: https://docs.google.com/<secret>/viewform";     
  var subject = "lunch order submission";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }


ScriptApp.newTrigger("startAcceptingResponses")
   .timeBased()
   .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY)
   .atHour(9)
   .nearMinute(25)
   .create();


 ScriptApp.newTrigger("stopAcceptingResponses")
   .timeBased()
   .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY)
   .atHour(18)
   .nearMinute(00)
   .create();

 ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmails")
   .timeBased()
   .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY)
   .atHour(18)
   .nearMinute(55)
   .create();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post, but for anyone trying to use the above code:

> Frequency is required if you are using atHour() or nearMinute()

From: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#atHour(Integer)

So write your function like this:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("startAcceptingResponses")
   .timeBased()
   .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY)
   .atHour(9)
   .nearMinute(25)
   .everyWeeks(1) // The frequency
   .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the function `.onWeekDay(...)`.
What I do now instead is just remove it and use `.everyDays(1)` instead,
and in the function itself I test the current day:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
if(day != ScriptApp.WeekDay.SUNDAY) { // I don't work on Sunday
  //...
}
```